# Laravel Fractal add success message to response

Tags: laravel, serialization

Is it possible to add a success message to a JSON response using Fractal? I would like the structure to look like the following

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Clients found",
  "_metadata": {
    "total_count": 2
  },
  "data": {
    "clients": [
      
    ]
  }
}
```

I have written the following code to return the data

```
$response_data = fractal()
    ->collection($person_array)
    ->transformWith(new ResponseTransformer())
    ->toArray();
```

Do I need to create a new serialiser to get this format? I have been following this documentation https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/fractalistic but there is no option to add extra key values such as `success: true`.

I also want to use this format for all my API responses, is it possible to create a generic `Transformer` which returns what ever array data I pass into it instead of creating a Transformer per Model?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel fractal allows to add meta data to collections :

```
fractal()
->addMeta([
    'status' => [
        'success' => true,
        'code' => 1,
        'message' => 'Test'
    ]
])
```

Resulting JSON output

```
 "meta": {
    "status": {
      "success": true,
      "code": 1,
      "message": "Test"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if this was the only way to do it or not. is there a way to rename the meta key? I would like it to be `_metadata` so it appears above the data

Comment: You can read this : https://github.com/spatie/fractalistic#including-meta-data